# List names of symbols with its arguments

Tags: symbols

Before Mathematica 10.0, when there was no `Association`, the suggested way of using datastructures [*map*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), was to abus arguments of undefined symbols:

```
foo["a"] = 1
foo["b"] = 1
```

I would like to explore the *keys* of the map `foo`. Defined symbols can be explored by `Names` command. However, it does not work. I have tried:

```
Names["foo*"]
Names["foo[*]"]
Names["foo[\"*\"]"]
Names["foo[a]"]
```

which gives:

```
{"foo"}

{}

{}

{}
```

The manual is also clearly wrong:

> Names["string"] gives the same list of names as ?string.

While `?"foo"` and `?foo` lists all my elements, `Names["foo"]` only returns `{"foo"}`, instead of `{"foo[\"a\"]","foo[\"b\"]"}` or something similar.

**What is the proper way of extracting all the members of the map `foo`?**

Why do I ask? From time to time I still feel it nice to use the syntax to give my variable names some structure and later go through them using `Map` for example, if I only had possibility to get the list of keys.

Edit: As I wrote in the very beginning, I am aware of `Association`. Abusing arguments of symbols is, however, way more flexible. For example, for some arguments, a function could be called instead of a value from a map. See for example see [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoization).

(Using Mathematica 11.3)

Comment: Does `DownValues[foo]` provide what you want? Or `DownValues[foo][[All, 1, 1, 1]]`?

Comment: Since you're talking about keys, you might be interested in [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Yes, perfect! I would accept this answer. ("proper" is so relative :))

Comment: @LukasLang, Thanks, but see the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning a comment into an answer.*

To get the replacement rules:

```
DownValues[foo]
```

> {HoldPattern[foo["a"]] :> 1, HoldPattern[foo["b"]] :> 2}

To get only the "keys":

```
DownValues[foo][[All, 1, 1, 1]]
```

> {"a", "b"}

Note that this may lead to problems, if `DownValues` rules with more general patterns are also used in `foo`. Maybe

```
Cases[DownValues[foo][[All, 1, 1, 1]], _String]
```

will circumvent some issues. But in the end, the programmer is in charge of keeping the definitions of `foo` free from any disturbing `DownValues`. Another reason (beyond performance) why `Association` should be prefered if possible. (Towards performance: If you have to make many request into an `Association`, using `Lookup` will in general be a lot faster than `Map`ping the `Association`.)

## Remark towards performance

Evaluate this in your notebook to realize that Mathematica's symbol lookup (or rather lookup of `DownValues`) is not unbeatably fast.

```
keys = StringJoin /@ Tuples[Alphabet[], {4}];
values = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[keys]];
queries = RandomChoice[keys, 1000000];

a = AssociationThread[keys, values]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r1 = Lookup[a, queries]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, Listable];

MapThread[With[{x = f[#1]}, x = #2] &, {keys, values}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r2 = Map[f, queries]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r3 = f[queries]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r4 = Table[f[x], {x, queries}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4
```

This is what I get on my machine:

> 0.33415
>
> 0.560602
>
> 1.24963
>
> 1.24715
>
> 1.12814
>
> 0.89728
>
> True

Comment: I appreciate the note on the problem. Regarding the performance: I doubt there is anything faster in Mathematica than symbol lookup like `foo["a"]`? Obviously `Lookup` and `Map` have very different application and should not be compared!

Comment: In case of doubts, see my last edit.

Comment: Now I see what you meant: `Lookup[a, queries]` vs `Table[f[x], {x, queries}]`. I thought you were talking about `Lookup[a, RandomChoice[queries]]`. Note, that `Table[a[x], {x, queries}]` is as fast as `Table[f[x], {x, queries}]` and thus the advantage is really in some bulk pipelining possible only with vectorized `Lookup`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The output of `?string` is either a structured list of names, if more than one name matches `string`, or first a list of a single name followed by a list of definitions, which may include [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html), [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html), [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html), `SubValues`, `FormatValues`, and so forth. A list of definitions is not the same as a list of names.  `Names[string]` just gives the names and not the definitions.  The documentation is not wrong, strictly speaking in light of this distinction, imo; however, without the distinction in mind, the documentation might suggest the equivalence of the two, which compromises its clarity.

The OP's example shows only one name, `` Global`foo `` in the blue cell, in the output for `? foo`.  It is followed by a list of two definitions in the third cell of the image.

[image]

You can get the definitions displayed from the undocumented `` Language`ExtendedDefinition ``:

```
Language`ExtendedDefinition[foo]
(*
  Language`DefinitionList[HoldForm[foo] -> 
    {OwnValues -> {},
     SubValues -> {},
     UpValues -> {}, 
     DownValues -> {
       HoldPattern[foo["a"]] -> 1, 
       HoldPattern[foo["b"]] -> 1},
     NValues -> {}, 
     FormatValues -> {},
     DefaultValues -> {},
     Messages -> {}, 
     Attributes -> {}}]
*)
```

There's another similar function `` Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[foo] ``.

Comment: Note, that I was interested in the names and not the definitions. And `?` gives me a list containing all definitions, while `Name` only finds the "head symbol", and this is what I find contradicting with the documentation.

Comment: @Johu Note that `foo["a"]` is not a name, but part of the definitions.  Perhaps my characterization was too broad, but what you're seeking is part of the definitions.

Comment: Alright... you might be right about the definition vs name thing. Will try to look it up. Thanks!

Comment: @Johu If you want more than just the `DownValues` (and `?` shows more when there is more), then ``Keys /@ Values /@ Last@ First@ Language`ExtendedDefinition[foo]`` should get you started.  Maybe apply `Flatten` to it.  I don't know if you want the `HoldPattern` wrappers, but they keep `foo["a"]` etc. from evaluating.